# Important topics in visual force

Tags: visualforce

I am new to Sales force can anyone tell me important topics in visual force or basic topics to be covered.

Comment: I would suggest reading through the Visualforce developer's guide as a starting point; all of the major topics are in there. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/

Answer (score 7):

You may want to take a look at our [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce) tag info. You will find some important liks for the beginner to start working with Visualforce:

[image]

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/visualforce/info